# How to search facets using wildcard search

Tags: xquery, marklogic

How to return all values starting with Ar* when we search for a facet

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"
at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options := 
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <values name="entity">
      <range type="xs:string">
        <element ns="http://www.com/mynamespace" name="country" />
     </range>
    </values>
    <return-metrics>false</return-metrics>
  </options>
return search:values("entity", $options)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this with `search:values`. It does take a [`start` parameter](http://docs.marklogic.com/search:values#start), for which you could specify `Ar`, but that would only provide a lower-bound, not an upper bound. Proving a range query for upper and lower bound won't help either if you have concurrent values in your document fragments.

In case you can use cts functions directly, I'd say use [`cts:value-match`](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-match). That can work with your wildcards directly:

```
cts:value-match(cts:element-reference(fn:QName("http://www.com/mynamespace", "country"), "Ar*")
```

HTH!

Comment: You could build a [custom constraint](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/search-api#id_49750) that does the `cts:value-match` call that @grtjn shows, putting that into the "start" function.

Comment: Here's another example showing the technique @Dave Cassel is recommending: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12645728/3582140